# Dynamically updating grid with grid_remove() in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

My goal is to create a Tkinter GUI with a Scale that-when updated-will change the number of scales underneath the original scale. Currently my slider will work with only the highest 2 values in its range, and I cannot figure out why.

I have tried to use grid_remove() and grid_forget() to no success.

I have also used these posts as references to get as far as I am now:

- [grid_remove not removing widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589548/grid-remove-not-removing-widgets)
- [grid()/grid_remove() functions don't do i would expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47759657/grid-grid-remove-functions-dont-do-i-would-expect)
- [Python grid_remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567459/python-grid-remove)
- [Tkinter Grid Dynamic Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704736/tkinter-grid-dynamic-layout)
- [tkinter grid_forget method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70827359/tkinter-grid-forget-method)
- [grid_forget() not working for dynamic checkbox in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152668/grid-forget-not-working-for-dynamic-checkbox-in-tkinter)

flowchart of code:
create slider > on slider update read value of slider > if slider value = x then remove or add sliders

My current code is:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry()

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


def makeslider(sliderval):
    print(str(sliderval))
    global slider2, slider3, slider4
    if int(sliderval) == 1:
        slider2 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)
        slider2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider3.grid_remove()
        slider4.grid_remove()
    if int(sliderval) == 2:
        slider2 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)
        slider2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider3 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)
        slider3.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider4.grid_remove()
    if int(sliderval) == 3:
        slider2 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)
        slider2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider3 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)
        slider3.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider4 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)
        slider4.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)


# slider
slider1 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=3, command=makeslider)
slider1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was in the way I called my command and how I structured my command.
I used this tutorial [Remove Widgets from grid in Tkinter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-widgets-from-grid-in-tkinter/)

- Define your widgets outside of the def and instead only assign them a
  grid space within the def.
- Use lambda x: instead of lambda: because it has a positional argument
  (use lambda: if button and lambda x: if scale)
- use widget names as variables in the command

I was able to change my code to:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry()

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


def makeslider(slider2,slider3,slider4):
    sliderval=int(slider1.get())
    print(str(int(sliderval)))
    if int(sliderval) == 1:
        slider2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider3.grid_remove()
        slider4.grid_remove()
    if int(sliderval) == 2:
        slider2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider3.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider4.grid_remove()
    if int(sliderval) == 3:
        slider2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider3.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)
        slider4.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)


slider2 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)
slider3 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)
slider4 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=5)

slider1 = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=3, command=lambda x: makeslider(slider2, slider3, slider4))
slider1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```